# Best way to achieve the following layout

Tags: views, theming

I am pretty new to Drupal, I have a Content Type with a "Field Collection" say like below..

1. Title
2. Banner Image
3. Details - Field Collection Type (Short Title, Description, Links)

I would like to achieve the following style of output, basically upon "User Selection" in the LHS the RHS side should refresh and show the selected Field Collection item's Description. What is the best possible way to achieve this in Drupal 7 (Views with Contextual Filters?, Cycle? or Rotator components etc). Please advice.

[image: Desired output]

**Edit: It's only the Content area shown in the picture, there will be a Menu/navigation system wrapping this. Hence this actually becomes 2nd level navigation for that page/node.**

thanks,
Vasanth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like some form of a slideshow you're after. If you're on D7, try the [Field Slideshow module](http://drupal.org/project/field_slideshow). You may need to do some preprocessing to get the Titles linked as Pagers to the slideshow (currently no option to specify a field collection field as a pager). The module comes with 3 template files for next/prev and pager and main slideshow which you can copy to your theme folder and override.

After you install the module, go to the Manage Display of your content type and set the Format of the field collection field to Slideshow and then click the gear icon to configure.

To use titles as pagers, first go to Manage Display of your content type and set the Pager type to "Image". Ignore the Pager image style configuration.

Then paste the following code to your theme's template.php file and replace THEMENAME with the name of your theme, and replace FIELDNAME with the machine name of your title field inside the field collection:

```
/**
 * Override template_preprocess_field_slideshow_pager
 * @param array $vars
 */
function THEMENAME_preprocess_field_slideshow_pager(&$vars) {
    $pager = $vars['pager'];
    
    if($pager == 'image') {
        $items = $vars['items'];
        
        $thumbnails = array();
        
        foreach($items as $item) {          
            $thumbnails[] = '<a href="#">' . $item['FIELDNAME']['und'][0]['safe_value'] . '</a>';
        }
        
        $vars['thumbnails'] = theme('item_list', array(
          'items'       => $thumbnails,
              'attributes'  => array(
                'id'    => 'field-slideshow-' . $vars['slideshow_id'] . '-pager',
                'class' => 'field-slideshow-pager slides-' . count($vars['items']),
              ),
        ));
    }
}
```

Clear all caches.

To include any long text type fields in the slideshow that you couldn't select in the Manage Display gear icon configuration, simply print them inside the field_slideshow.tpl.php, if you know a bit of PHP it should be easy. All the fields should be available to you inside the tpl file in `$items` array. Look for the line that reads `foreach($items as $num => $item)`

Comment: Hi, this is exactly what I am looking for. Only part not clear is how I could customize the Field Slideshow's Pager part, any links for this would really helpful. Otherthan this it's exactly what I am looking for, Thanks!!

Comment: @Vasanth edited my answer to include some guide to make titles as pagers.

Comment: Hi Baysaa.. just tried as per your guidelines, and it worked like a charm :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try [Single Page Website](http://drupal.org/project/single_page_website) module. Its a good option for this kind of website. Just create menu and give proper link.

> This module provide the ability to display the content of all menu items of the menu that you indicate in settings on the Single Page Website module.
>   On the page 'single_page' the links in the menu will be replaced to the links to the correspondent anchors.
>   You can set URL 'single_page' as front page of your site, and your visitors will see the Single Page Website. But it will be the site managed by Drupal 7.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the suggestion - the output is exactly what I am looking for. It's my mistake that I missed to mention it's the 2nd level navigation which I'm looking for on my site. The screenshot is just the "Content Area" and I missed to include the Navigation/menu system around it. So what I am planning is to Theme My Custom Content Type and then include custom jQuery to dynamically show/hide respective regions on RHS. Thanks for your suggestion :)